# How can I open a  .themepack file in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, themes, file-roller

I have install `p7zip-full` and `p7zip-rar` packages to help me in this situation, but default archive of Ubuntu `file-roller` can not open "Windows 7 theme pack" files, which uses .themepack extensions. How can I open this type of file or is there any known method to do that in Ubuntu. In Windows "7zip" program can open this kind of file easily. I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: For anyone interested, after finding that solution, here you can download a lot of "themepack": http://windows.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/themes

Comment: The same question (and answer) is also for .deskthemepack extension (theme pack for Windows 8 / RT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying several hours and links, I think, I've finally got the right solution, that allow me to open a `.themepack` file with `file-roller`.

1. First install `cabextract` package, by entering the command on `terminal`.

   - Press `super+a` key on Unity, type `terminal` on dash and click on the terminal icon.
   - Type `sudo apt-get install cabextract` command on the terminal, provide your password and hit enter.
2. Then type again in the terminal `sudo apt-get install assogiate`, this will install the `assogiate` program on computer. (alternatively, you can install it through "Software Center".
3. Then open the assogiate program, by pressing `alt+f2` and typing `assogiate` on the 'Run a command' box.

   - This will open `assogiate` program in graphical window. On the **left** hand side pane, click on **Search Results**. then type `cab` on the **bottom** text box on the **right** pane.
   - Double Click on the desired application name. ( In this case, it is **vnd.ms-cab-compressed** ).
   - On the new **Edit type application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed** window, Click on **Filenames** tab. Then click on **Add** button, type `*.themepack` on the new **Add filename rule** dialog window. Click **close**, and then Exit the program.

Now you should open any `*.themepack` extensions file with `file-roller` just like any other compressed tar, zip etc files.

If you want this settings persists globally (system wide), you should open the program in the step 2 as `gksu assogiate`, all other procedure is same.

Credit goes to MistreLion, answerer of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34474/how-do-i-handle-wim-image-files).

---

### Update

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04 and in this version, you need only to install `p7zip-full` package.

Open a terminal, type the following command , provide password and hit enter. That's the all required (*of course, after connecting to the internet*).

`sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`

Comment: I am still not fully satisfied with this answer, 'cause it is done all within a program. I should be able to do this manually

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: @EliahKagan, meaning doing it without the needs for any software. I am trying to do something with the files in `/usr/share/mime/packages/*`,trying to invent some method eliminating the needs of downloading the extra software. Can you help me in this (mime type, file types etc).

Comment: Wow, very interesting. I did not know that file-rollers looked at declared mime type for the extension.

Answer (score 3):

A `.themepack` file for Windows 7 is actually a CAB archive (like a `.cab` file). You can open such a file with `cabextract`. To get it, install the `cabextract` package.

Then either run `cabextract name.themepack` (replacing **`name`** with the name of the theme pack filename before the `.themepack` extension), or [configure the Archive Manager to open `.cab` files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5273/how-do-you-view-the-contents-of-a-cab-file) and open it graphically from Nautilus.

Comment: The command line method worked for me.But I want it to be done graphically and your provided method(link) not working for me, since I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Good point. Nautilus in recent versions of Ubuntu doesn't make it easy to open files with unknown extensions, with the application of your choice. I'm not sure what the best way is to specify the application to open `.themepack` files, but [this method](http://askubuntu.com/a/82417/22949) should still work.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, but that link doesn't help me. But I myself find a solution.

Comment: I don't understand, why downvote on this question ?. May be some guys built a habit of downvoting every post with title containing 'Windows'. I think, I should change the title of the question now.

Comment: @AnwarShah I'm curious as to what happened when you tried to use Thunar to associate `.themepack` files with `file-roller`. Or does Thunar not currently provide that degree of configurability? In any case, I'm glad you were able to find the answer. As for the downvote, who knows why someone downvoted your question (I upvoted it), maybe by accident, it would've been nice if they'd left a comment, but random upvotes cancel out random downvotes in the long run (more than cancel out for your reputation points, since upvotes count more than downvotes).

Comment: Actually I did not tried the `thunar` method, since it requires a download, and I personally do not like thunar, because they come with `exo-utils` package, which gave me some pain in past. (There are some question regarding that issue also in this site). And thank you for your vote, and I got the idea now.(I am still new, only 4 days)

Answer (score 2):

If you change the .themepack extension to .lzx, the preinstalled Archive Manager can extract if just fine. (Thanks to 7zip for dispaying the compression type in its file list.)

However, MistreLion's solution would avoid the annoyance of renaming a file each time. (I simply prefer not to install additional software on my system if I don't need to.)

If there's a way to make Archive Manager aware that the .themepack extension is actually .lzx, it would be a far more elegant approach.

Comment: Thanks. I've solved the problem already and in the recent Ubuntu versions i only need to install `p7zip` package

Comment: Cool, just wanted to put in my 2 cents. BTW, today with the release of Windows 8, M$ seems to have changed the format to .deskthemepack files, and these appear to extract natively in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you download a file with a themepack extension, to use the images all you have to do is extract the contents using cabextract. Nothing else is needed.